# Pass Parameter to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I'm trying to pass two parameters to a JavaScript function.
Unfortunately this give me error.

Here is the function

```
    function load(do,div)
    {
        var do;
        var div;
        document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '<img src=\'/images/spinner.gif\'>';
        $('#'+div).load('rpc.php?'+do,
        function()
        {
            document.getElementById('spinner').innerHTML = '';
            $('#'+div).show('slow');
        }
    }
```

And I call it like this:

```
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="load('limit','mydiv');">Get Limit</a>
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`do` is a reserved word in [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). Change the variable name to something else. Additionally, don't re-declare the arguments in the function body. So remove the 2 `var` lines from the top of your function body.

If you're curious what the `do` keyword is for, it's for `do...while` loops where the condition is evaluated at the end, not the beginning of the loop. It's used something like this:

```
do {
    // do stuff in loop at least once
} while (some_condition_is_true);
```

For more info check out [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp).

Comment: ... and remove the two declarations which are the overriding the arguments.

Comment: re-declaring variables with same argument name, doesn't effect the arguments.

Comment: @Luca Matteis: Interesting. I didn't know that. Even so, it's unconventional enough that I still advise removing those lines.

Comment: Interesting. This is a-logical.

Comment: @BalusC: What exactly is a-logical? The fact that re-declaring variables has no effect, or my decision to leave the recommendation to remove the re-declaration in my answer despite knowing the former?

Answer (score 2):

`do` is a reserved word in JavaScript.

http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you are redefining do div again in function and they are overriding the scope of passed parameters?